# Finding which COLUMN has a max( value per row

Tags: sql-server

MSSQL

Table looks like so

```
ID    1   | 2  |  3  |  4  |  5 
AA1   1   | 1  |  1  |  2  | 1
```

any clues on how I could make a query to return

```
ID  |  MaxNo
AA1 | 4
```

, usign the above table example? I know I could write a case blah when statement, but I have a feeling there's a much simpler way of doing this

Comment: can you please elaborate more, i did not understand your question well. I mean you want the output as ID as MaxNo -> do you mean to have it as 5 and AA1 as 4, I mean what is the calculation..??

Comment: He wants to find out which column contains the maximum number per each record. And his output is the ID of the record (row - AA1), and the column which contains the maximum number (4th column).

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu that is correct, I can't think of a better way of explaining, can you help?

Comment: *‘…but I have a feeling there's a much simpler way of doing this’* – there may also be a saner way of storing your data. If you find yourself in the need of finding a maximum value across columns, maybe you should consider storing the data in rows.

Comment: @AndriyM it's data we actually paid a company for, believe it or not. That is it's raw format that goes straight into SQL for analysis, so I'm kinda doing that part at the moment... Government, eh?

Comment: Ooh, in my country (and in my experience) people working in governmental companies are the kind that is hard to convince to change anything. Very conservative folk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to get these comparable items, correctly<sup>1</sup>, into the *same* column, and then use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to find the highest valued row<sup>2</sup>:

```
declare @t table (ID char(3) not null,[1] int not null,[2] int not null,
                 [3] int not null,[4] int not null,[5] int not null)
insert into @t (ID,[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]) values
('AA1',1,1,1,2,1)

;With Unpivoted as (
select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Value desc) rn
from @t t UNPIVOT (Value FOR Col in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) u
)
select * from Unpivoted where rn = 1
```

Result:

```
ID   Value       Col                       rn
---- ----------- ------------------------- --------------------
AA1  2           4                         1
```

---

<sup>1</sup> If you have data from the same "domain" appearing in multiple columns in the same table (such that it even makes *sense* to compare such values), it's usually a sign of attribute splitting, where part of your data has, incorrectly, been used to form part of a column *name*.

<sup>2</sup> In your question, you say "per row", and yet you've only given a one row sample. If we assume that `ID` values are unique for each row, and you want to find the maximum separately for each `ID`, you'd write the `ROW_NUMBER()` as `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Value desc) rn`, to get (I hope) the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a cross apply where you do `max()` over the columns for one row.

```
select T1.ID,
       T2.Value
from YourTable as T1
  cross apply
    (
    select max(T.Value) as Value
    from (values (T1.[1]),
                 (T1.[2]),
                 (T1.[3]),
                 (T1.[4]),
                 (T1.[5])) as T(Value)
    ) as T2
```

If you are on SQL Server 2005 you can use `union all` in the derived table instead of `values()`.

```
select T1.ID,
       T2.Value
from YourTable as T1
  cross apply
    (
    select max(T.Value) as Value
    from (select T1.[1] union all
          select T1.[2] union all
          select T1.[3] union all
          select T1.[4] union all
          select T1.[5]) as T(Value)
    ) as T2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cdbda/1)